Enabling VNC server
I want to install and configure VNC server on Ubuntu 22.04. In addition, I use GNOME desktop, and I don't want to use RealVNC...I'd prefer to use another alternative such as Tiger VNC.
However, the guides I have seen don't work and when starting the server the desktop system crashes...
Any idea what could be wrong?
I have a Raspberry PI running Raspbian with PIXEL and it was really simple to setup--enable VNC in the preferences and then connect to the Raspberry PI using TigerVNC client. Moreover, when connecting to the Raspberry PI from the client (MacBook) the native display session does not close, and the VNC client simply mirrors the native display.
Is it possible to do the same thing in Ubuntu 22.04?

Very confusing question. First you talk about a non Ubuntu OS that is not supported on this site and then say you are trying to make this work on Ubuntu 22.04. Please edit the question and make it clear. Thanks.
